# SSRS Extract substring from string before the second string

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a field which is like the following 4444-4444-TestingItem1.
Is it possible for me to extract the field up until 4444-4444. 
if so how would I do this? What function would I use within SSRS. 
Please note It could be any number of characters before the first dash and before the second dash.

How can this be achieved within SSRS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tim and Alejandro both give good answers that work with your example. This is a combination of the two, as an SSRS expression rather than SQL, and handles strings with more than two dashes.

```
=LEFT(Fields!FIELD.Value, InStr(InStr(Fields!FIELD.Value, "-") +1, Fields!FIELD.Value, "-") -1)
```

Answer (score 7):

In SSRS you can use `LEFT` and `InStrRev` functions:

```
=LEFT(Fields!YourField.Value,InStrRev(Fields!YourField.Value,"-")-1)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using a combination of `CHARINDEX` and `SUBSTRING`:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(field, 1, CHARINDEX('-', field, CHARINDEX('-', field)+1) - 1)
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: This question was about SSRS, and the answer is for SQL. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

pat1 : Find first position of char is non-numeric or "-"

pat2 : find first position of "-" and follow non-numeric

```
    SELECT a.s,LEFT(a.s,PATINDEX('%[^0-9-]%',a.s)-1) AS pat1
              ,LEFT(a.s,PATINDEX('%[-][^0-9]%',a.s)-1)  AS pat2
    FROM (VALUES('4444-4444-TestingItem1')) a(s)
```

```
s                      pat1                   pat2
---------------------- ---------------------- ----------------------
4444-4444-TestingItem1 4444-4444-             4444-4444
```